# Sending Commands to a serialport

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I'm trying to send this to `SerialPort` to command the devices' LED to lit on.

```
SData(0) = 85
SData(1) = 170
SData(2) = 36
SData(3) = 1
SData(4) = 2
SData(5) = 0
SData(6) = 1
SData(7) = 0
SData(8) = 0
SData(9) = 0
SData(10) = 0
SData(11) = 0
SData(12) = 0
SData(13) = 0
SData(14) = 0
SData(15) = 0
SData(16) = 0
SData(17) = 0
SData(18) = 0
SData(19) = 0
SData(20) = 0
SData(21) = 0
SData(22) = 39
SData(23) = 1
SerialPort1.Open()
For i = 0 To 23           
   SerialPort1.Write(Chr(SData(i)))
Next
SerialPort1.Close()
```

I don't get response from the device or anything. Then i noticed that the module freezes for 2 seconds, i think it's the loop.

I think i need to know the steps of how a `SerialPort` runs from open to close.

Btw, there's a original copy of this but it was in VB6

here's whats working: `MSComm1.Output = Chr(SData(i))`

Comment: Serial ports are slow, you close the serial port before any data can be sent.   The SerialPort class also doesn't like you to quickly call Open after calling Close, a detail that MSDN warns about.  So never write it like this, call Open() when your program starts up and don't call Close() until it ends.  Not calling Close at all is fine as well.

Comment: i see. does the method `SerialPort.Write()` correct? *without the open and close. I'm having problems sending this data.